# Neither User 10060 nor current process has android.permission.serial_port

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am trying to access a barcode reader connected to an android device using serial port. I'm using `android.app.smdt.SmdtManager` to access the device. But whenever I try to access the serial port, it throws an exception

```
Neither User 10060 nor current process has android.permission.serial_port
```

I have searched a lot and tried different solutions, but nothing works.
I have tried the below manifest configurations,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SERIAL_PORT" />
```

---

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.SERIAL_PORT"
            android:label="serial_port_label"
android:protectionLevel="signature|privileged" />
```

---

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.SERIAL_PORT"
                android:label="serial_port_label"
    android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem" />
```

---

Nothing worked.
Then I installed the app to system directory by using the below commands

```
adb remount
adb push file_name_comes.apk_here /system/app/
adb shell chmod 644 /system/app/file_name_comes_here.apk
adb reboot
```

Still same error.

Is there any way to solve this issue **other than creating a custom firmware**.

**-- Edit 1**

I'm using Lollipop 5.1.1 Only.

**--Edit 2**

Also changed SELinux mode from `Enforcing` to `Permissive`.

Still no change.

Comment: Have you implemented runtime permissions if you run app on Marshmallow Devices

Comment: I'm using 5.1.1 device only.